# CRM 2011: Fetch Error

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I have an error with a script that contains multiple fetch in crm 2011... the error is that the key dosent exist & is coming from:

```
<condition attribute='bc_type' operator='eq' lable='Credit' value='948110001' />
```

if no recordes exist with the condition it fails rather then just pass & return 0
any ideas?

i do declare

```
decimal TotalDed = 0;
decimal TotalCre = 0;
```

The code:

```
string value_sum = string.Format(@"         
            <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
                <entity name='bc_llbalance'>
                    <attribute name='bc_units' alias='ded_sum' aggregate='sum' />
                       <filter type='and'>
                        <condition attribute='bc_learninglicense' operator='eq' value='{0}' uiname='' uitype='' />
                        <condition attribute='bc_type' operator='eq' lable='Deduction' value='948110000' />
                       </filter>
                </entity>
            </fetch>", a);

                    EntityCollection value_sum_result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(value_sum));

                    foreach (var b in value_sum_result.Entities)
                    {
                        TotalDed = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)b["ded_sum"]).Value);
                    }

                        string cre_sum = string.Format(@"         
            <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
                <entity name='bc_llbalance'>
                    <attribute name='bc_units' alias='cre_sum' aggregate='sum' />                      
                        <filter type='and'>
                        <condition attribute='bc_type' operator='eq' lable='Credit' value='948110001' />
                        <condition attribute='bc_learninglicense' operator='eq' value='{0}' uiname='' uitype='' />                        
                        </filter>
                </entity>
            </fetch>", a);

                            EntityCollection cre_sum_result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(cre_sum));

                                foreach (var c in cre_sum_result.Entities)
                                {
                                    TotalCre = ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["cre_sum"]).Value);
                                }
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `foreach` loops

```
foreach (var c in cre_sum_result.Entities)
{ 
    if(c.Attributes.ContainsKey("cre_sum"))
    {
        TotalCre += ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["cre_sum"]).Value);
    }
}
```

You need to test whether the value is there before trying to cast is. The error you are getting is a generic .Net one ([more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception.aspx)).

If no value is found in the field for a particular record, CRM will not include that property and so it will be missing in the collection.

You are also using `=` and not `+=`. This mean the total is the value of the last record, rather than a sum.

Consider the following:

```
var ListOfNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 ,4 }
var total = 0;
foreach (var c in ListOfNumbers)
{
    total = c;
}
Console.WriteLine(total.ToString());
```

would output `4`

```
var ListOfNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 ,4 }
var total = 0;
foreach (var c in ListOfNumbers)
{
    total += c;
}
Console.WriteLine(total.ToString());
```

would output `10`

Comment: Thanks that work great :) foreach (var c in cre_sum_result.Entities)
{ 
    if(c.Attributes.ContainsKey("cre_sum"))
    {
        TotalCre += ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["cre_sum"]).Value);
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a typo there:

```
operator='eq' lable='Credit'
               ^^^^^
```

should be

```
operator='eq' label='Credit'
               ^^^^^
```

Comment: you are right i had, however it didnt seem to change anything as works of the value, i have just removed that now. <condition attribute='bc_type' operator='eq' value='948110000' /> thanks for pointing that out tho :)

Comment: See it works if i have records that match both conditions for it to count on but sometimes there may only be one record type

Answer (score 0):

In both the foreach loop you have to check whether that alias cre_sum and ded_sum contains any value...

for example,

TotalCre =c.Attributes.Contains("cre_sum") ? ((Decimal)((AliasedValue)c["cre_sum"]).Value): 0;

so it will check whether it contains any value if yes it will return sum else return 0.

Do this for both loops.

Hope This Helps !!!